# Mode formula not working

Tags: excel-formula

I'm struggling with MODE I have some surveys I am analysing.

Currently using =MODE(IF(AJ15:AJ24<>0,AJ15:AJ24))
One Question's answers are:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
3
```

the formula is giving `#VALUE` error as there are no repeated numbers. Can anyone suggest how to get round this so it doesn't show an error.

Comment: With the data you have shown, what are you expecting as an answer?

Comment: you have 7 repeated zeros.

Comment: When I test with your formula it does not give a value error.  If shows 0,  if I reduce it to 0,1,2,3 then I get the error #N/A.  I get the Value error when I force your IF statement to return FALSE instead of leaving it blank.

Comment: If you're getting an error, you might have numbers formatted as strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
=iferror(MODE(IF(AJ15:AJ24<>0,AJ15:AJ24)),"")
```

If your formula does not result in an error then the result of your formula is displayed.  When your formula generates an error, "" or nothing is displayed.